# Trying to read backwards from a binary file

Tags: c++, file, while-loop, binary

I have a binary file with the integers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 stored in it. I'm trying to start reading the file at 10, then move backwards until I get to 1. This is what I have

```
int count = 1;
    file.seekg(-sizeof(int) * count, ios::cur);
    while (file.read((char*)&z, sizeof(int))) {
        cout << z << " ";
        count++;
        file.seekg(-sizeof(int) * count, ios::cur);
    }
    cout << endl;
```

The output only gives me 10,9,7,4. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `ios::end` in the [`seekg`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) calls, or always move backwards by the size of two elements (`-2 * sizeof(int)`, not adjusted by `count`), one for the element you just read and one for the element you are about to read.